# the conversion of char data type to datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range on server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

I am getting error on server as

> the conversion of char data type to datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range

With below code

```
DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text.ToString());                    
DateTime sysdate = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace("-", "/"));
```

Comment: What is the value of txtEndDate.Text.ToString()

Comment: @yusuftezel: It goes `""` when I dont add any values

Comment: The value, when you get the exception?

Comment: when I go to save the form with details

Comment: why you replace sysdate?. If you show this value then create another string and replace those string .

Comment: @Naveen: can u show how u are telling this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `sysdate`? As far as I can tell, you want to zero out the time part? If so, use `DateTime sysdate = DateTime.Now.Date;`

Answer (score 0):

Use these code;

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(now);
DateTime sysdate = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));
string repl = sysdate.ToString().Replace("/", "-");
```